# alternative to UIView setCenter

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, performance, uiview

My app, which is a game, includes a `CADisplayLink` timer which calls a function that instructs about 20 calls to `UIView setCenter:` for the various objects on screen every frame.

Time profiling it, this accounts for about 30% of all activity in the game and drastically reduces performance on older devices (anything lower than 5th generation ipod touch or iphone).

Are there any lightweight, low-overhead alternatives I can use to move objects (specifically `UIViews`) around the screen every frame?

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, the `center` property of these `UIViews` must be set EVERY FRAME. I have a number of tiles that represent the ground in my game. They zip across the screen, only to be replaced by new tiles. After fiddling with the code for a couple hours to change the `UIView`s to `CAlayer`s, I have it working at absolutely no performance gain. There surely is a better way to do this.

[image: a section of the Time Profile stack trace]

Some code to give a general idea of what is going on:

```
for(Object* o in gameController.entities){
    [o step:curTimeMS];
}
```

`gameController` is, as one would think, a class that takes care of the main game functions. It includes its list of entities, which are all the objects on-screen. The `step` method on each of these entities is a virtual function, so it is specific to each entity - the `curTimeMS` variable is simply a timestamp so the object can calculate its delta position. In essence, each entity updates its `layer.position` property every frame, moving it at an appropriate speed across the screen.

Comment: Since it's a game, have you checked SpriteKit already? It's a great framework, fun and easy to use.

Comment: @Winston Agreed but I think he wants to run on earlier systems.

Comment: Yes, that's right because he mentioned 5th generation ipod touch or iPhone on his question.

Comment: @Winston As matt said, I do want to support earlier systems, but SpriteKit seems like a good way to go in the future, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: You'll have a good time using SpriteKit.

Comment: What is in the views that you are using? Do they have their own drawRect implementations? Can you show the instruments trace?

Comment: @jrturton an image of a portion of the stack trace using the time profile instrument is included in the question now. As you can see, a large portion of time is spent on the `setPosition` method. This is not the only example of this happening in the game - there are many other objects on screen using this method too. The views contain artwork (PNG files) that i have created and are no more than a few kilobytes. No drawRect methods have been used or overridden.

Comment: Turbo rocket penguin sounds fun! Is [Ground step:] the method that's called from the display link, or renderScene? Can you include some code, ideally the annotated one from instruments that gives you the percentages?

Comment: @jrturton Thanks! You'll be able to find it on the app store very soon hopefully! Code is included above with a basic overview of how it works. To answer your question, `[Ground step:]` is called from `renderScene`.

Comment: If renderScene is called every time, then it doesn't look like step is your problem. The bulk of the work is being done in the rest of the renderScene method.

Comment: @jrturton A `CADisplayLink` is used to call renderScene every frame, and then it calls each entitie's `step:` method. As you could see, the ground alone was taking an enourmous 11% of the entire computing time throughout the game. This is only the ground. If I listed the entire stack trace, you would see that other entites, such as the background and clouds in the game are taking up similar computing time.

Comment: @jrturton also, you can see in the picture that `[CALayer setPosition]` accounts for 5.1% of the computing time, and that's just within the `[Ground step:]` method!

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using UIKit (or core animation) for games. I tried for an app that wasn't a game, but an art app that was "game like", and somewhere around having about 40 custom UIViews on screen things started to break down. I don't think you can do a real-time game using the framework. This is what Sprite Kit is for.

Answer (score 0):

If you need performance, do not use `UIView`. It is not designed to be fast.

Instead, have a single `UIView` that takes up the whole screen, with a bunch of `CALayer` objects inside the one view. Move the layers around.

`CALayer` works by talking direct to the GPU, so it's very fast. Perhaps even faster than OpenGL. `UIView` is using `CALayer` internally so they both behave approximately the same. The only real difference is any change to the position of a `CALayer` will be animated by default. You can easily turn the animation off, although in a game you probably want animation.

Your other option, of course, is to use OpenGL. But that's a lot more work.

EDIT: here is some sample code for changing the position of a layer properly: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW8

Comment: I have read in other SO answers that `CALayer` and `UIView` do not have any significant performance differences. So it is worth changing my code to support `CALayers` rather than `UIView`s? I do have experience using OpenGL, but as this project is nearing completion, it's preferable not to do a huge code re-write.

Comment: I can confirm after restructuring a bunch of code that `CALayer` makes no improvement whatsoever to the performance, and when tested in the time profile instrument all the same underlying functions are called.

Comment: @Fitzy so you're finding it is slow to move a layer from one position on the screen to another? And you only have 20 layers? That hasn't been my experience at all, I've had code that moves 200,000 layers or more in a single hit with no performance issues. Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: @Fitzy I updated my answer to show how Apple suggests you should move the position of a layer along a specific path. Note they don't use `setPosition:`. However I have personally made very demanding use of `setPosition:` with no performance issues. Again I'd like to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend SpriteKit. It is a [very powerful game / 2d animation framework created by apple.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html). [Cocos2D is also a very powerful framework of similar type.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org)  You can create a new SpriteKit game straight from XC[image]

If you want to stay in house with just `UIKit` stuff, check out [`UIView block based animations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html). Here is the jist of it.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:numberOfSecondsTakenToAnimate animations: ^{
    // do you animation here. i.e.: move view frame, adjust color.

} completions: ^(BOOL complete) {
    // when the animation is complete, code in this block is executed.

}];
```

I just remembered [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html). It is used in tandem with `UIView`s to create simple 2d graphics and is **very** powerful and **very** fast. Here is the jist of that.

```
CGContextRef cntxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextBeginPath(cntxt);

CGContextMoveToPoint(cntxt, <x>, <y>);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(cntxt, <x>, <y>);
CGContextClosePath(cntxt);

[[UIColor <color>] setFill];
[[UIColor <color>] setStroke];

CGContextDrawPath(cntxt, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Note: things in < > are variables / values specified by you.

If you want to go all out, [take the time to learn Open GL](http://www.opengl.org). Beware, I have heard that this is extremely hard to learn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as discussed in previous comments, I deliberately have NOT used SpriteKit in order to support earlier iOS versions and devices.

Comment: I know about `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration: animations:` but I didn't consider using it as the basis for frame adjustment. Do you think this will result in a performance gain?

Comment: @Fitzy not sure, but it looks extremely smooth. Also check out my edit about Core Graphics if you are looking for performance. I have personal experience with this framework, and I can attest to its performance

Comment: I just saw your edit, It seems like some people are advising to use it while other answers I've seen on this site explicitly say that there is negligible difference between Core Graphics and UIKit as UIKit's `UIView` is an extremely lightweight wrapper around `CALayer`

Comment: @Fitzy I was capable of creating a conways game of life simulator with over 400000 cells on an iphone with core graphics. I think its pretty fast.

Comment: Ok, I believe you. I'll look into the options. As for OpenGL, I have moderate experience with it and can confirm that it is definitely overkill for this little 2D game. :)

Comment: In my edited question, I state that the changeover to Core Graphics has absolutely no effect on performance. It seems some alternative is needed for the `setPosition` method that is less performance-intensive.